# ¿Cómo tomar la primera aparición de un producto?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una un tabla en `sql` y quisiera saber como puedo hacer para agregar a una consulta la primera vez que aparecio un producto, y la ultima vez que aparecio el mismo.
la tabla tiene los siguientes campos:

```
id_sc2_producto, id_sc2_corrida, talle, marca, tipo, color, sexo, descripcion, stock, moneda, precio, precio original, fecha_alta, url_imagen, url_producto, origen
```

creacion de tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE sc2_detalle
(
id_sc2_producto VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
id_sc2_corrida INT NOT NULL,
talle VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
marca VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
tipo VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
color VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
sexo VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,  
descripcion_aux VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
descripcion VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
stock INT NOT NULL,
moneda VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
precio NUMERIC(10,2) NOT NULL,
precio_original NUMERIC(10,2) NOT NULL,
fecha_alta DATETIME,
url_imagen VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
url_producto VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
origen VARCHAR(VARCHAR 150)
)
```

**el campo `id_sc2_corrida` funciona como version, o sea que un producto puede estar varias veces en la tabla, pero con otro numero de `id_sc2_corrida`**

por ejemplo:

```
id_sc2_producto | id_sc2_corrida
abcd1                  1
abcd1                  2
```

hice la siguiente consulta:

```
select c.*, p.*,d.id_sc2_corrida corrida_aux ,d.tipo,d.fecha_alta

from (
    select distinct id_sc2_corrida from sc2_detalle with (nolock)
    ) c
cross join
    (
    select distinct id_sc2_producto, talle, color,precio,precio_original,stock,origen from sc2_detalle with (nolock)
    ) p
left join sc2_detalle d with (nolock) on d.id_sc2_corrida  = c.id_sc2_corrida  and d.id_sc2_producto = p.id_sc2_producto  and d.talle = p.talle and d.color = p.color
```

y con esto lo que hago es tener todos los registros que me interesan, ya que pueden haber productos que no esten en algunas `id_sc2_corrida` , entonces muestro un `null` en la columna '`corrida_aux`'(cuando ese producto no existe en esa version). Ahora mi duda es como obtener el `id_sc2_corrida` minimo, y el `id_sc2_corrida` máximo de ese producto, y agregarlo a esta consulta. De tal modo que en la salida de esta consulta sea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente agregarle arriba de la consulta `max(d.id_sc2_corrida)` y `min(d.id_sc2_corrida)` pero solo hacia una comparación por fila.

Espero que me hayan entendido, 
saludos y se agradece cualquier ayuda

Comment: Puedes hacerlo por separa con dos consultas distintas cogiendo max-min y uniendolas con un UNION

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no te entendí mal, lo que necesitas es una consulta agrupada por `id_sc2_producto` y sobre cada grupo obtener la `id_sc2_corrida` mínima y máxima:

```
select d.id_sc2_producto, 
       min(d.id_sc2_corrida) as 'MinCorrida',
       max(d.id_sc2_corrida) as 'MaxCorrida' 
       from sc2_detalle d
       group by d.id_sc2_producto
```

Esto, obviamente puedes usarlo como una subconsulta y utilizar `MinCorrida` y `MaxCorrida` para volver a hacer `JOIN` sobre `sc2_detalle` para obtener las fila completa que corresponda al máximo o mínimo `id_sc2_corrida`